# 1/2 factor in the definition of Riemann Xi

Tags: complex-analysis

in the definition of Riemann Xi function:

$$\xi(s) = \frac{1}{2}s(s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\zeta\left(s\right)$$

$s(s-1)$ is used to "cancel" the zeta pole,

other factors preserve the symmetry:   $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$

why is there 1/2 factor?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934221

Comment: If I recall coreectly, this is just a normalization factor, so that the value at 0 and 1 is 1.

Comment: I think $\xi(0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

In Riemann's original paper, he just writes (using a different notation for the Gamma function):

$\xi(s) = (s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2+1)\zeta(s)$

which can easily be obtained from your formula, since:

$s/2\Gamma(s/2) = \Gamma(s/2 +1)$.

In other words, the $1/2$ factor is needed so that the $\Gamma$ function can "absorb" the $s$ factor.